# How select max of string in linq to nhibernate

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, max, linq-to-nhibernate

I have a **Card** class . This class has a **Code** column by string type.
I have a linq-to-NHibernte query for select max of codes.

```
var q = SessionInstance.Query<Card>()
       .Max(x => x.Code);
```

For example data of this column is : `18950,9850` and expect result is `18950` and result is `9850`.

I changed this query to it :

```
var q = SessionInstance.Query<Card>()
       .Max(x => int.Parse(x.Code));
```

But above query has a runtime exception by this message :

```
Expression type 'NhMaxExpression' is not supported by this SelectClauseVisitor.
```

Why?

Answer (score 1):

NHibernate doesn't know how to convert your `int.Parse` call to SQL.

Easiest solution: use SQL.

More complex and/or fun: extend the NHibernate LINQ provider to support that call. Google [extending nhibernate linq](http://www.google.com/search?q=extending%20nhibernate%20linq) for some links.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Convert.ToInt32 instead of int.Parse .
Take a look here: 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adodotnetentityframework/thread/6c8892db-8df7-4174-b9b0-764dc1df82ad

Comment: I tested by Convert.ToInt32. This is the same error. Both is correct in linq to object but linq to nhibernate not support none solution.